# Draw table over image in HTML to save my life

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a HTML page, but I don't know anything about devlopment.

I need to transform [this image](http://oi63.tinypic.com/2u8uty9.jpg) into an html page, replacing the black blocks with dinamic texts.

I tryed to learn html tables, divs, etc... but its not for me, really.

This page need to be centered on browser, because I'll send it on e-mails.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a place to get your work done (I wish it work that way); create that page as much as you cant and post the code here with the issue or how you want it to improve and we'll be able to help you then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you really need to step back and take the time to learn some basics about working with html.  I notice you say you need to email the page, does that mean you're really trying to build just an email template rather than a website?  The two are similar, but have some different considerations.  Either way, I'd suggest looking at a site similar to http://ccm.net/faq/173-how-to-create-your-own-website to try and understand the very basics first, as otherwise your question is really very broad.